# How to extract Polygons from a SQL Server geometry value

Tags: sql, spatial

I have a set of data in SQL Server 2008 for each country.

I want to add a geometry value for each describing the the land mass of each country so I have found the TM_World_Border shape file and imported it into a the db - All well and good.

The issue is the existing schema has Alaska and Hawaii as separate entries from the rest of the USA where as the shape file only has one entry for all three combined.

Could you please point me as to how I can extract Alaska and Hawaii into their own geometry values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so looks I solved the issue by creating a second polygon which bounds around the area I am interested in (Think Clipping Mask) and selecting the intersection of the polygon and the original Geography value

> declare @Bounding Geography
>
> declare @USA Geography
>
> declare @Result Geography
>
> select @USA = geog from dbo.country_10m where id = 238
>
> select @Bounding = Geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON((-130 54, -130
> 23, -60 23, -60 54, -130 54))', 4326);
>
> ```
>  SELECT @Result = @USA.STIntersection(@Bounding)
> ```
>
> update foo
>
> set geog = @Result
>
> where id = 2

Comment: Actually it would probably be easier to use something like Quantum Gis (http://www.qgis.org/) to split the data into separate polygons. I do it all the time to "prepare" my data before importing it to Sql Server. It has a small learning curve but it's definitely a valuable program to add to your GIS toolset.

Comment: Ok cheers - I shall have a look at that - I am actually using your MVC tile server blog post as a starting point to build my own http://build-failed.blogspot.pt/2012/06/custom-map-tiles-part-4.html . Very good set of posts & kudos the getting spatials to work with the latest version of NHibernate